# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many collection methods not showing up on object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a problem with `has_and_belongs_to_many` in a Rails 4 app. The setup is as follows:

- A User can have several Roles
- A Role can have several Permissions

Since many Users can share the same Roles, and many Roles can share the same Permissions, and I don't need special connection models between them, I am using `has_and_belongs_to_many` for both these relationships.

Here are the models (stripped of validations):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :permissions
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end
```

The join tables are named as per convention:

```
create_table "permissions_roles" do |t|
  t.integer "role_id"
  t.integer "permission_id"
end

create_table "roles_users" do |t|
  t.integer "role_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
end
```

Roles <-> Permissions works great, but Users <-> Roles seems to work only one way. I can attach Users to Roles, but not Roles to Users – the collection methods do not exist on the User objects. From the rails console:

```
> r = Role.first # Fetch a role
> r.users        # Empty list of users -- so far so good
> u = User.first # Fetch a user
> u.roles        # NoMethodError: undefined method `roles' for #<User:0x007fe67562f580>
```

Any idea what could be going on here?

**Update:**

When I run `User.has_and_belongs_to_many :roles` from the console, the association is correctly set up and I can run `User.first.roles` without issue. It seems the association for some reason isn't set up when the application is bootstrapped.

Comment: does the output of `u.methods` include `roles`?

Comment: Surely permissions would be programmatic? I mean, do you need a database to house them?

Comment: @dax: No, it does not.

Comment: @Rich Peck: Well, yes, and we're changing that, but that's besides the point here. The relationship should still work.

Comment: Good point - thanks for clarification :)

Comment: does `r.users.methods` include `roles`?

Comment: I suppose you are doing it wrong.The HABTM relation should have one join model with the corresponding two other models on which the relation is set.Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @dax: No, it doesn't either.

Comment: give this a try: 
`r.reflect_on_association(users)`
`u.reflect_on_association(roles)` - if the output of these is the same, then i don't know :P  if it's not, i suggest you take a look at your `user` and `role` tables (not the join tables)

Comment: @Pavan: No, that's a `has_many :through`-relation. HABTM does not need a join model.

Comment: ah, or better: `r.reflect_on_all_associations` and `u.reflect_on_all_associations`

Comment: Actually it does need I think so by seeing this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: read that link again, Paven. First sentence: A has_and_belongs_to_many association creates a direct many-to-many connection with another model, **with no intervening model**.

Comment: @dax oops! Misjudged by seeing the picture of it.Apologies to the OP.

Comment: dax: The association shows up when doing `Role.reflect_on_all_associations`, but not when doing  `User.reflect_on_all_associations`. This is weird.

Comment: not sure why this would work, but try changing order of habtm in Role.rb?

Comment: maybe check out the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference)

Comment: Do u have additional columns other than the foreign keys?

Comment: @dax: I tried changing the order, it does not seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using has_many, :through

Here is an example

From rubyonrails.org:

```
class Assembly < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :manifests
  has_many :parts, through: :manifests
end

class Manifest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assembly
  belongs_to :part
end

class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :manifests
  has_many :assemblies, through: :manifests
end
```

More ressources on:

1. [the-has-many-through-association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)
2. [choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, it was extremely project-specific. All our models need to be used across multiple projects, so they live in their own gem. Turns out there was a different User model in another location that superseded the one in the gem.